# Closing an Angular Material dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Calling $mdDialog.cancel() from the controller will close the dialog. But is there a way of not using a controller to close the dialog box like directly from the html ? I want something like this to work:

```
<md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button ng-click="$mdDialog.cancel()" style="margin-right:20px;" >
        Ok
      </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: sure ... if you pass `$mdDialog` to your scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `show()` code, you can create a child scope and add the `close()` function:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    ...
    scope: angular.extend($scope.$new(), { close: function() {$mdDialog.cancel();} })
});
```

Then in your dialog's HTML, just use `ng-click="close()"`.

Alternatively, you can pass the `$mdDialog` object as a property of your scope.

However, it's even more code than creating a controller (which can also be created inside the `show()` function).

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
<md-button ng-click="cancel()"></md-button>
```

And in your dialog controller

```
$scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mat-dialog-close` to the button you want to trigger the close event from

Example: `<button mat-dialog-close> Close </button>`

Answer (score -2):

You can bind an scope into the dialog config:

```js
$mdDialog.show({
          targetEvent: $event,
          template:
            '<md-dialog>' +

            '  <md-dialog-content>Hello {{ employee }}!</md-dialog-content>' +

            '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
            '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
            '      Close Greeting' +
            '    </md-button>' +
            '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
            '</md-dialog>',


          scope: $scope,
          preserveScope: true


        });
```

For more info about the config properties you can see the dialog config documentation in [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)